# Create and use data tables in netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans, datatable

I have a table with:

```
vegetable name -- calcium contents -- Potassium contents -- vitamins -- fibers-- price (etc)
```

Let's say there are 5 entries (rows) in the table and I have to initially feed the data manually, like a first one time data feeding.

My requirement/problem is:

1. On a GUI when I select a vegetable name from a drop down menu I should get the contents displayed and then all of them should get added to get final score except the 'price'.
2. On the GUI if I select the 'vegetable name' and any one of the other 'property' (like 'fibers') then only that value should be displayed. e.g query-- spinach, fiber ?  answer spinach-fiber = 20 unit., or spinach-vitamins = 40units etc.
3. I also want help in what type of database I should use here and how to populate the data for accessing it in the program later on. I believe its a simple data table of small size so what is the most efficient way of doing this?
   Specific help with code will be of great help as I am absolutely new to java and netbeans.

Also, can I have a separate GUI for adding/appending further data from user in the same table? If yes, how is it done please? 
I am using Netbeans 7.1.2.

After some search I got info about MySQL datatables in netbeans. (http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html)
I have created and made entries in the table but do not know how to access them for my questions 1 and 2 above. Also not sure if it is the right data table that I should be using for such simple use.

Comment: This sounds more like a GUI type of problem rather than a MySQL problem. When you say GUI is it a HTML interface? Or a Swing interface? Please clarify your question a little more. Can you connect to the database? Can you execute queries? Without a lot more detail this question will not be answered.

Comment: Its a swing interface but used only for getting the choice from the user. once the input query is made i have to retrieve data from the table and get answer. I am able to connect to the database but do not know how to execute the queries. I don't know the syntax and the appropriate COMMANDS/FUNCTIONS to search the name and get required data from the table (basically a newcomer). can you suggest some online examples. So its more of a basic java programming question on how to use data tables.

Comment: further i don't know if i have to connect to the database everytime in the same manner (manually) as suggested in the webpage [http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html] and [http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html]. Is there a way by which i can connect to the data table automatically once i run the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to learn about **JDBC** first. Just to clarify connecting to a database inside the IDE is generally used for more development/administrative type duties and you **WONT** be using it in your Swing program.

So for example you need to load a set of test data to test a function you would typically use either the MySQL workbench or load it via the IDE. However you will not connect this way when you run a program.

What you need to learn is how to connect to a database from a front end, how to execute a query and how to display the query. At this point I would suggest getting a couple of books on JDBC or even doing a google search for JDBC introduction tutorials.

Get to learn JDBC without thinking too much about the front end. Do a couple of examples and then once you are familiar with JDBC then work on the front end.

You might want to spend time on learning basic SQL as well as this will be needed to properly query your database. I am assuming you have not done any SQL.

Here is a reasonably good link to a site with information that you might want to use http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-jdbc.html

Just remember the IDE(Netbeans) basically uses JDBC to allow you to connect and manipulate data. So while it is based on JDBC the IDE database explorer is **NOT** the tool you will be using when programming your swing interface.

Comment: thanks for this input/insight. I will study and revert. It was just that i am  in a hurry to finish this program that i was looking for short-cuts, or ready made and specific answers. But now it seems i have to get down and get my hands dirty.